Sending JSON strings from ESP32 web client to Apache web server
I'm trying to perform a POST operation from a web client application running on an ESP32-WROOM-32 to a web server running on Windows 11 using Apache. On the backend I'm trying to use JavaScript to handle the received data (JSON string). The problem is that I can't see/receive the JSON string sent by the ESP32, although on the VS Code terminal(from the ESP32 side) I get:
I (79753440) HTTP_CLIENT: HTTP POST Status = 200, content_length = 334
I (79753440) HTTP_CLIENT: HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED
So, I assume the data has been successfuly sent. I'm using the esp_http_client example.
I have already
1. Activated the reverse proxy on Apache using the mod_proxy module:
ProxyPass /post http://192.168.0.101:8000/
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

2. Written JavaScript and html codes to handle the sent data(I'm really a newbie in js/html):
const intervalID = setInterval(get_user_ID,1000);

function get_user_ID()
{
 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var requestURL = "/post";
    xhr.open('POST', requestURL);
    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
    {       

        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        console.log(response);

        document.getElementById("esp_response").innerHTML = response.User;        

    }
    
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script async src='serverJS.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>ESP32 get data</h1>
            <label id="esp_response_label">ESP32 response: </label>
            <div id="esp_response"></div> 
</body>
</html>

As a result, my html labels are printed correctly but I still get no data on the web browser console. Tried out the fetch API but no success. In one of the approaches I was getting response = null on the console. What could I be missging?
Just in case, I leave my esp_http_client piece of code as well:
#define HTTP_ENDPOINT "192.168.0.101"
static void http_rest_with_url(void)
{
esp_http_client_config_t config = {
    .host = HTTP_ENDPOINT,
    .path = "/",
    .query = "esp",
    .event_handler = _http_event_handler,
    .user_data = local_response_buffer,    
    .disable_auto_redirect = true,
};
esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);

// POST
const char *post_data = "{\"User\":\"User1-1919\"}";
esp_http_client_set_url(client, "http://"HTTP_ENDPOINT"/post");
esp_http_client_set_method(client, HTTP_METHOD_POST);
esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Content-Type", "application/json");
esp_http_client_set_post_field(client, post_data, strlen(post_data));
err = esp_http_client_perform(client);
if (err == ESP_OK) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP POST Status = %d, content_length = %"PRId64,
            esp_http_client_get_status_code(client),
            esp_http_client_get_content_length(client));
} else {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "HTTP POST request failed: %s", esp_err_to_name(err));
}

esp_http_client_cleanup(client);

}

I'm confused.  It looks to me like you have two clients here, both trying to send a POST request somewhere.  Where is the server?

Indeed. The server is the PC running apache(with the javascript code). I assumed that the browser is also a client for a server running on the background of the PC, so I performed a GET to fetch the data POST'ed by ESP32. On another hand,  even changing to POST on the js script doesn't fix the issue.

Somewhere, you have code on the server listening on port 8000, which receives the proxied request from Apache, parses the fields from that request. and sends back a response to the caller.  You haven't shown us that code at all.  EVERYTHING here is client code.

I've edited the post. Regarding handling the request: I've shared the javascript code on 2. that I'm trying to use on the server side to handle the proxied request and send back an answer. Regarding "EVERYTHING here is client code" : well, on 1. I've shared a piece of my apache configuration file (httpd.conf file) which states on its very first line "# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file...". I can't really get your point very well, please be more specific.

and... that is all I have.

Your Apache configuration says that all requests to the URL "/post" should be routed to another server process listening on port 8000.  NOWHERE here have you shown us an application listening on port 8000.  The Javascript in "2." is not run on the server, it is sent to a browser and runs there.  document.getElementById, for example, is a browser function, not a server function.

I can catch your point now, thanks. So, as far as I can understand, I need some server specific code(written in node.js/PHP) to listen to the port 8000? That is probably was I was missing in my implementation.
